# Comparison between: Maximum Absolute Difference & Min Steps in Infinite Grid

Tags: arrays, euclidean-distance

There are two questions that I am trying to draw a comparison between:

```
Q1: Maximum Absolute Difference
You are given an array of N integers, A1, A2 ,…, AN. Return maximum value of f(i, j) for all 1 ≤ i, j ≤ N.
f(i, j) is defined as |A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|, where |x| denotes absolute value of x.

Q2: Min Steps in Infinite Grid 
You are in an infinite 2D grid where you can move in any of the 8 directions : 
    (x,y) to 
    (x+1, y), 
    (x - 1, y), 
    (x, y+1), 
    (x, y-1), 
    (x-1, y-1), 
    (x+1,y+1), 
    (x-1,y+1), 
    (x+1,y-1)
```

I was reading up about the Q2 and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272649/maximum-absolute-difference-in-an-array) stackoverflow question. Here, the accepted answer reduces this question to `given a list of points in 2D space (x[i], y[i]), find two farthest points (with respect to Manhattan distance)`

Reading up, I think both these questions are exactly the same except that Q1 is asking for Manhattan Distance in 1D and Q2 is asking for Manhattan Distance in 2D.

I am not very clear about this. Can someone please verify my observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nice that you try to draw a comparison between two similar situations. However, it looks like you are driving too fast to stay on the right road. Henceforth I will be moving somewhat slowly so as to stay on the correct path.

What is generally considered as a distance? You might react, hi, I know what is a distance! Cool then. Here is [the widely-agreed general definition of a distance according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#General_metric) as well as my years of practice in math and computer science.

> In mathematics, in particular geometry, a distance function on a given set $M$ is a function $d: M \times M \to R$, where $R$ denotes the set of real numbers, that satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - $d(x,y) ≥ 0$, and $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$. (Distance is positive between two different points, and is zero precisely from a point to itself.)
> - It is symmetric: $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$. (The distance between $x$ and $y$ is the same in either direction.)
> - It satisfies the triangle inequality: $d(x,z) ≤ d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. (The distance between two points is the shortest distance along any path). Such a distance function is known as a metric. Together with the set, it makes up a metric space.

Now let us write out explicitly our distance functions and metric spaces.

1. In Q1, $f$ defines a distance function on all integers from 1 to $N$ such that $f(i,j) = |A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|$. All integers from 1 to $N$, together with $f$ forms a metric space, say, $M1$.
2. Let $\Bbb Z^2$ be all the grid points in 2D. Let $d2$ be the minimal steps needed for you to move from point (x,y) to point (p,q), where each step must be one of the eight kind of steps listed. Then $\Bbb Z^2$, together with $d2$ forms a metric space, say, $M2$. Note that $d2((0,0),(0,1))=1$, $d2((0,0),(1,0))=1\,$ and $d2((0,0),(1,1))=1$.
3. Denote the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry#Formal_definition) by $ma$, i.e., $ma((x,y),(p,q))=|x-p| + |y-q|$. $\Bbb Z^2$, together with $ma$ forms a metric space, say, $MA$. Note that $ma((0,0),(0,1))=1$, $ma((0,0),(1,0))=1\,$ and $ma((0,0),(1,1))=2$.

Now please follow my observations below.

- $M1$ can be considered as a part of $MA$. Why? Define $e$: $i\mapsto (A(i),i)$. Then you can see that $d1(i,j)=ma(e(i), e(j))$, i.e., the distance between $i$ and $j$ in $M1$ is the same as the distance between $e(i)$ and $e(j)$ in $M2$. You can imagine that $e$ just embeds all integers $1, 2, \cdots, N$ in $M1$ to $MA$, keeping their pairwise distances. This is the simple reason why [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273280/835743) to Q1 can reduce it to `given a list of points in 2D space (x[i], y[i]), find two farthest points (with respect to Manhattan distance)`.
- $M1$ may or may not be considered as part of $M2$. It depends on how sequence $A$ is defined.

  1. Let $A_k$ be 0 for all $k$. Then $M1$ is just those 1D integers with their usual Euclidean distance among them. It can be embedded easily into the $M2$, keep their pairwise distances.
  2. Let $A_1=0$, $A_2=1$, $A_3=0$, $A_4=1$. Then you will find the four integers 1,2,3,4 in $M1$ has pairwise distance 2 except that $d1(1,4)=4$. However, you cannot find that kind of 4 points in $M2$. This particular example shows that your intuition "both these questions are exactly the same" is suspicious.
- The distance in $M2$ is not a Manhattan Distance. You can have 8 points each of which is 1 distance away from any given points in $M2$. For example, $(1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (-1, 1), (-1,0), (-1,-1), (0, -1), (1, -1)$ are 1 distance away from $(0,0)$ in $M2$. However, there is only 4 points each of which is 1 distance away from any given point in $MA$. For example, $(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0, -1)$ are 1 distance away from $(0,0)$ in $MA$. You can also check that $(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)$ is the vertices of an equilateral triangle in $M2$ with side length 1. However, you will not be able to find such an triangle in the Manhattan space $MA$.

---

Hopefully I have cleared all your doubts. Here are a few exercises for you to arrive at a better understanding of the concepts.

Exercise 0. Verify that $d1$, $d2$ and $ma$ are distance functions according to the definition.

Exercise 1. Suppose $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n$ is an increasing sequence of integers. Show that $M1$ can be considered a part of $M2$. Show that $M1$ can also be considered as a part of $MA$.

Exercise 2. Find 4 points in $M2$ whose pairwise distance are the same. Show that there is no 4 points in $MA$ whose pairwise distances are the same.

Exercise 3. Given an $m$ by $n$ grid in $M2$ with its bottom left corner $A$ at $(0,0)$ and its upper right corner $B$ at $(m, n)$. $0\le m \le 20$. $0\le n \le 20$.  Compute the number of paths starting at $A$ and ending at $B$, where you must always move closer to $B$ along the path.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation. I am trying to grasp it in parts and am stuck at: `ma((0,0),(1,1))=1 , ma((0,0),(1,1))=1 and ma((0,0),(1,1))=2`. Why is it that for the same pair of points, the distance is sometimes 1 and sometimes 2?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typos. I must have been interrupted while copying and pasting my examples during my long writing. I just corrected those typos. Please take another look at my examples for $d2$ and $ma$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the edits have helped me understand that point. But now, I am stuck at: `the distance between i and j in M1 is the same as the distance between e(i) and e(j) in M2`. Why can we state this? I understand this has to do with the mapping you defined, but it doesn't follow linearly from that. What am I missing? Assuming it is the pairwise distance, how are we connecting this to the question `(given a list of points in 2D space (x[i], y[i]), find two farthest points (with respect to Manhattan distance))`

Comment: The distance between $i$ and $j$ in M1, $f(i,j)$ is $|A(i)-A(j)| + |i-j|$ **by definition**.  The distance between $e(i)=(A(i),i)$ and $e(j)=(A(j),j)$ in M2, $ma(e(i), e(j)$ is $|A(i)-A(j)| + |i-j|$ **by definition**. So those two distances are the dame. Image $i$ in M1 **is**  $e(i)$ in M1 (and $j$ in M1 **is** $e(j)$ in M2), you can see the maximal distance among the former is the maximal distance among the later.